# Dropped an index and recreated it in PostgreSQL 9.2, not used anymore

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a table with 15M rows, with two indexes; one of them is a very simple BTREE on a string column.

While trying to optimize some queries, I created a new partial index on the same column. Using EXPLAIN I noticed that the index wasn't used, so I tried to drop the original full index.

The partial index was still not used (a sequential scan was used instead). After some other tests, I dropped the new partial index and restored the old one. So the situation should be exactly the same as at the start. But the re-created index is not used, not even with the simplest of queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 'status'
```

It still insists to do a full scan. I tried analyze, then vacuum analyze, nothing.
Before recreating it, the same identical index was used. Why did this happen? How can I make PostgreSQL use the index again?

This is the explain:

```
"Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..350340.22 rows=246 width=579)"
"  Filter: ((status)::text = 'partial'::text)"
```

This is the index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_table_on_status
  ON table
  USING btree
  (status COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Comment: Have you `ANALYZE`D the table?

Comment: Yes, I used both analyze and vacuum analyze

Comment: Please paste both indexes you have (or had) on the table as well as the sql you ran to generate the explain you have shown?

Comment: Thanks Joishi, I got the solution from IRC - it was a long running transaction, the indexes themselves were OK

Comment: ok. Glad to hear it.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the mystery on pg irc channel - I had a long running query (idle in transaction) and they told me that a new index doesn't get used until all transactions that started before its creation don't finish.

Killed the transaction, and now the indexes are back to normal.